# Two versions of the Breusch-Pagan test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, heteroscedasticity, breusch-pagan

I have learned (and it is the case for instance in Woolridge's *Introductory Econometrics*) that for testing heteroskedasticity with the BP test, the sample statistic is $nR^2_{\hat{u}^2}$, that follows a $\chi^2(k)$ distribution.

But I have come across another textbook that says that one must consider $\frac{SSE}{2}$, that is also supposed to follow a $\chi^2(k)$ distribution.

So I understand the intuition behind theses tests (if there is homoskedasticity, the second equation should be "poor"), but I am a bit confused by these two versions, especially as they are supposed to follow the same distribution. For a specific example, there is no reason that $nR^2_{\hat{u}^2}$ and $\frac{SSE}{2}$ would be equal, so that it is possible to imagine cases where in one version, one would accept the hypothesis of homoskedasticity, and that one would reject it with the other version.

Can someone enlighten me ? Either by bringing back the two together, or by the maths begin it, or by any other way that would be nice.